# How to get the location of a place on google map

Tags: android

i'm developing an android application similar to Google places app.

I want a functionality to obtain the location of a place on google maps in my application. How do i achieve this?

This is the use case:

1. Using GPS my current location's lat and long will be passed using the notification service.
2. Then when i click on the button restaurant,the list of restaurants in that particular location will be displayed(all information is being retrieved from the server that i created using grails).
3. Then i select a restaurant's name from the list being displayed.and then in the user interface there is a button called "MAP" .
4. Upon click of the "MAP" button, the location of the restaurant i have chosen must be displayed on Google maps.

Comment: Just want to clarify : No 1 you don't need a Notification Service. Just plain HTTP Service will do. No 2 you don't need to select from your own server. You can use Google Places API.

Comment: 1.then how else will i get the lat and long of my current location? and to use google places api  we need the key right.i tried getting the google places API key. they rejected my request.they said i dint have a proper website.

Comment: Try create one in appspot. It's owned by Google and I hope they will accept their own hosting. :) For no 1: You can create a webservice in your server. Notification Service is a way for server to tell that some updates happened. It's a push from server to client. Not the other way around ( client to server and server returns )

Comment: i'm a novice.i would like to know more about the notification service. if you got any link from which i can read and learn that'll be great.could you please elaborate on what you just said? what should i create in appspot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the thing that you can't do - displaying the restaurant on the map, or having just the name of the place, you wish to find it's address/coordinates on the map?

You can follow the official Android tutorial on the subject - Point 2 in this article: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/… Probably this article will be useful as well: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Part 1 and 2 guide you through the creation of a Map activity (you should start a new map activity when the user taps on MAP button) and how to add an overlay to the map. In the article the overlay is the android robot. The other articles uses a pushpin as an overlay. Overlay, on the other hand, is .. a picture that is displayed on the map. In your case - some pinpoint put on the coordinates of the restaurant. Once you've created the map activity, you can follow my second link and look for title "Adding Markers". It's very well explained.

Comment: displaying the restaurant on the map

Comment: You can follow the official Android tutorial on the subject - Point 2 in this article:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html Probably this article will be useful as well: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: point 2 is already done .i want to display the restaurant chosen on the map. point 4 in this article is what is still not done.

Comment: Can you give some source, because it's hard to figure out what exactly is the problem - the article says how to add an overlay to the map(display the restaurant on the map) and you said it's done.

Comment: ya i said the list of restaurants is already being displayed. that is point 2. which i said is already done. what i said i cant figure out how to do is... when i click on the "MAP" button the restaurant must be displayed on the map.

Comment: Oh, ok - so the article on developer.android.com - Part 1 and 2 guide you through the creation of a Map activity (you should start a new map activity when the user taps on MAP button) and how to add an overlay to the map. In the article the overlay is the android robot. The other articles uses a pushpin as an overlay. Overlay, on the other hand, is .. a picture that is displayed on the map. In your case - some pinpoint put on the coordinates of the restaurant. Once you've created the map activity, you can follow my second link and look for title "Adding Markers". It's very well explained.

Comment: thanku for the links. hopefully i can do it.i'll get back here if i have any problem.

Comment: @Zh. Can you edit your answer so that the solution is in the main part of the post instead of a comment?  Thank you.